# Shifting data down in a table with both forward and reverse loops

Tags: excel, vba

Please see an abstracted example in the image below

[image]

Warning! I'm very new to VBA and still learning, so there might be some obvious mistakes in my code.

I have a very large table of data containing several rows and columns. The objective is to loop through a column containing a bunch of IDs and detect duplicates in a specific segment of the string. As soon as there is a mismatch in this segment, the row and new value is stored before a reverse loop begins that shifts everything below down the last duplicate down by four spaces.

The result is three blank rows after all duplicates (see image).

There's a few conditions that I have to meet for this code to be compatible with the software that secures this sheet:

- Inserting whole rows needs to be avoided, insert and shift down is okay
- Avoiding select is ideal
- No application enable/disable can be used
- The fewer individual cell changes the better

The idea is to loop through each of the columns to shift all corresponding values in that row down once I have perfected the first column. It would be great to avoid having to do so if there's a way to shift the whole range down instead of individual cells.

The second, reverse loop seems to be the problem.
I've tried several ways of looping using integer loops, range for loops, do while, and do until.
Please let me know if you need clarification! Thank you so much for your help.

```
Sub shiftValues()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Tab1=Raw Data")
Dim lastRow As Variant
    lastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row


Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A16:A" & lastRow)
Dim oldString As String
Dim newString As String
    newString = "newString"
Dim oldRow As Integer
    oldRow = 15 'Start of table

Dim beforeEqual() As String
    beforeEqual = Split(ws1.Range("A15").Value, "=")
Dim tar As Long    

    For Each cell In rng
        oldString = Right(beforeEqual(0), 2)
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And Len(cell.Value) > 6 Then
            beforeEqual = Split(cell.Value, "=")
            newString = Right(beforeEqual(0), 2)
            
            If newString <> oldString And cell.Row > 15 Then
                oldString = newString
                oldRow = cell.Row
                    tar = lastRow
                    Do Until tar = oldRow
                        Range("A" & tar + 4).Value = Range("A" & tar).Value
                        Range("A" & tar).ClearContents
                        tar = tar - 1
                    Loop
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to be sure, when you talk about a string matching, you ignore the numbers at the end, after the fruit names?

Comment: Yeah, we only care about a segment of the string, or the fruit name in the example provided. The real ID is much more complex, but the isolation and comparison of the string segment of interest is working.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want:

```
j = 0

For i = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1

If Range("A" & i).Value <> Range("A" & i - 1).Value And Range("A" & i - 1).Value <> Range("A" & i - 2).Value Then
    If j = 0 Then
        j = i
    Else
    End If
Else
    If j > 0 Then
        Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        j = 0
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! The bottom section definitely seems like an improvement over my process. It throws an error at the for loop at the top and doesn't seem to like 'For i = For i ='

Comment: Check the edit to my answer -- not sure what happened there